# SwiftUI run method on view when Published view model member value changes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, combine

I am having troubles with running view methods on published property value change. My playground sample code looks like this:

```
class MyFoo: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bar: String
    init(bar: String) {
        self.bar = bar
    }

    func setNewText(newString: String) {
        self.bar = newString
    }

    func runFunctions() {
        setNewText(newString: "Test")
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject let foo = MyFoo(bar: "bar0")

    init(){
        let barSink = foo.$bar
            .sink() { //THIS IS WHERE I GET ERROR "Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter"
                self.printResult(result: $0)
            }
    }

    func printResult(result: String) {
        print(result)
    }
}

let a = TestView()
```

Basically I know why I get this error in closure but I don't know how to go around it. Is this the right approach for running view methods on VM published property value changed?

I need this because I am using custom spinner that is not SwiftUI ready so I cant bind to it, and the only way to show/hide it is by calling its methods.

Any help would be most appreciated

Comment: try adding `@ObservedObject` before `let foo = MyFoo(bar: "bar0")` and make `MyFoo` inherit from `ObservableObject`: `class MyFoo: ObservableObject {}`

Comment: I have edited the question, but it doesn't fix the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how the playground works but I try to answer you question. I tested the code in the simulator and on a real device:

```
class MyFoo: ObservableObject {
    @Published var bar: String
    init(bar: String) {
        self.bar = bar
    }

    func setNewText(newString: String) {
        self.bar = newString
    }

    func runFunctions() {
        setNewText(newString: "Test")
    }


}

struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var foo = MyFoo(bar: "bar0")

    var body: some View {
        Text("Lolz")
            .onReceive(self.foo.$bar, perform: { lolz in
                self.printResult(result: lolz)
            })
    }

    func printResult(result: String) {
        print(result)
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

The `@ObservedObject` needs to be a `var`. With `onRecieve()` you can listen to the publisher and update UI or call a function.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thx so much, don't know if this is official "Apple" solution, but it works like a charm!!!

Comment: Well `onReceive()` is specifically designed to listen to publisher! :)

Comment: Yeah I know, I was referring to adding Text block which will never be used as Text block, It would be a good idea to create custom control, say ActionBinder or something like that. ActionBinder()
            .onReceive(self.foo.$bar, perform: { p in
                self.runSomeAction(param: p)
            })

Comment: You can just make a custom `View` `struct customView: View { var body: some View { Text("").onRecieve() }}` and you can even do this in your parent and `onReceive()` on the `customView`